# Which latch would work with this screen door?

Tags: repair, doors, patio, security, screens

I recently bought a used condo, and it has a sliding patio door.  The glass door works fine, but I noticed that the screen door is missing a latch.  Here is a photo:

[image: Screen door with missing latch]

Considering the holes in the door and the shape of the catch, what kind of latch would I need to replace the missing one?

Comment: Just a suggestion. Knock on a neighbors door introduce yourself as the new neighbor and ask to look at their door. All the units are likely the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!  It's an [Acorn Latch Kit](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-Sliding-Screen-Door-Acorn-Latch-Kit-Surface-Mount-Diecast-A-164/202597994).  Thanks for the replies.

[image: Latch]

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the catch that's there; buy a complete set: [sliding screen door latch](https://www.google.com/search?q=sliding%20screen%20door%20latch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

[image]

<sub>[source](http://www.fixingscreens.com/screen-door-locks-and-latches.html)</sub>